# Add multiple options in cmake flag in a shell script and run the shell script

Tags: shell-script, command-line, compiling, make, cmake

I want to run a set of commands from a bash script. How ever I don't know how to put the quotation in a bash script.

The following is the bash script which I want to run, how ever in the cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS I want to add another flag **-gcc-name=/path/bin/gcc**. I want to do it through a shell script and eventually run that shell script, which is going to give me the installation.

Please kindly suggest me a way to do this.

```
mkdir /g/g92/bhowmik1/installTF/ROSS;
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/g/g92/bhowmik1/installTF/ROSS -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-O3 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=mpicc -DARCH=x86_64 -DROSS_BUILD_MODELS=ON ..;
make;
make install;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the whole value:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/g/g92/bhowmik1/installTF/ROSS \
      -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS='-O3 -gcc-name=/path/bin/gcc' \
      -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=mpicc -DARCH=x86_64 -DROSS_BUILD_MODELS=ON ..
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also have a small doubt, regarding the question, why do we use single quotes, why not double quotes?

Comment: I used single quotes because nothing inside the quotes needs to be processed by the shell.

Comment: Thank you so so much, You are really helpful.

Comment: You’re very welcome! By the way, if answers to your questions are helpful, please accept them using the big checkmark — see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sure, I am pretty new to community, Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to Unix.SE!